# Analog to Digital converter module of MCU - Conceptual question

Tags: microcontroller, adc, c

Please consider the following codes:

```
//Code Sample 1
void func_val(void) 
{
  unsigned int val;
  ADCSC1 = 0x00; // sets the required channel.
  while(!ADCSC1_COCO); //check for conversion complete flag.
  val= ADCRL;
}

//Code sample 2
void EvalProx()
{
  unsigned int proxval;
  ADCSC1 = 0x02; // sets the required channel.
  while(!ADCSC1_COCO); //check for conversion complete flag.
  proxval = ADCRL;
}
```

Now both the samples are snippets from a bigger code, which compiles and works.
My question is about the concept of Analog to Digital Converters in MCU. 
`ADCRL` and `ADCRH` are the **registers** in which the converted values are stored.
`ADCSC` is the **status control register** in which I have specified two different channels to be used.

Question: The `ADCRL`/`ADCRH` are same for the two different setting of the `ADCSC` i.e. same for both the **channels**. So does the value of **`proxval`** influence the value of **`val`** when accessed? i.e. If **`func_val()`** is executed and then 
**`EvalProx()`**, is the value of **`proxval`** influenced by the **val**? (when both the values depend on `ADCRH` and `ADCRL`)

I hope I am clear. Before down voting this question, I request, please take some time to tell me why you have down voted, so I can improve my question.

Datasheet of the used MCU: [MC9S08DZ60](http://cache.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/data_sheet/MC9S08DZ60.pdf)

Specific Page Numbers: Chapter 10 :- Page 181,182- for `ADCRH` and `ADCRL`.

Comment: val and proxval are both local variables, known only inside their respective functions, so neither affects the other.  Both functions effectively do nothing, as val and proxval are lost when the functions exit.  Perhaps you've snipped too much to show your question properly?

Comment: This question has nothing really to do with ADCs per se. It's really a C question, with some incidental references to an ADC. EDIT: and now I see @DaveTweed has said exactly this in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that would be the case, Usually in a case like this the compiler would read the value of ADCRL and store it a location in memory that is associated with the variable val or proxval. You can verify this by looking at the generated assembly code by the compiler. But if your worried that's I would declare val and proxval as volatile variable. If val and proxval where pointers to ADCRL then yes calling one function would affect the other but as regular variable the value from ADCRL gets actually stored to variable

Comment: Thanks mate! that clears up a lot. a concurrent question: so what if i am not using functions and then accessing the ADCRH/ADCRL? and i really dont know how to read ALP code.

Comment: Even if your not using function, you should get the same behaviour because the data will be stored in some location in memory assign to the variable

Comment: No. It is not val and proxval that need to be volatile, but rather you need to insure volatile access to the ADC registers. Usually that done where they are defined.

Answer (score 7):

This question doesn't really have anything to do with the ADC specifically; what you're really asking about is the use of automatic variables inside C functions. The fact is that `val` and `proxval` don't even exist at the same time — each one only exists when its corresponding function is actually executing.

Automatic variables (variables declared inside a function and not declared as `static`) are allocated on the CPU stack (or a simulation of a stack if the CPU hardware doesn't support it).

It is possible that the same physical location on the stack is used for both variables, if the two functions are called from the same level in the calling hierarchy, and they have the same parameters.

Comment: Technically answer. Thanks for teaching tat part, didnt know at all!

Comment: and i really wish i could accept two answers, but i cannot!

Comment: I've heard/seen this mentioned in a few places but never fully understood it: how can a CPU not support a stack? Doesn't any architecture that uses subroutines (I'm pretty sure that's all architectures) have to push the return address onto the stack so it can return to where it called the subroutine from? The stack just means a section of memory with a pointer that grows in a certain direction and acts as a stack data structure no? I just don't understand how an architecture could not support a stack.

Comment: @NickHalden "supporting a stack" means (1) having an explicit stack pointer register, and (2) having primitive assembly instructions for manipulating the stack pointer register (like reti, which changes the program counter based on the stack pointer in order to return from a function call). You can emulate this without hardware support through emulation, which is compiler generated code that the same sort of things in RAM using variables. It's rare / uncommon to not have direct support for stack in any modern computer architecture.

Comment: There are many low-level microcontrollers that have hardware stacks for subroutine call/return and interrupt handling, but make it difficult if not impossible to store data (variables) there, and implementing a purely software data stack would be terribly inefficient. The 8051 is one classic example, and low-end PICs (PIC12/PIC16) are another. On these machines, the data stack is emulated by assigning static storage locations for automatic variables, with the amount of reuse of these locations being dependent on the sophistication of the compiler.

Comment: @NickHalden, great question (and good answer from Dave, too). Ask it on the site?

Comment: @ThePhoton http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/61946/4159 Here ya go.